# How can combine several ref() elements in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have several similar elements that are defined as follows:

```
<script setup>
const el1 = ref()
const el2 = ref()
const el3 = ref()
</script>

<template>
<h1 ref="el1"></h1>
<h1 ref="el2"></h1>
<h1 ref="el3"></h1>
</template>
```

I want to combine all of `ref` elements into a new reactive variable and use their attributes.

What is the best approach for handling this?

Answer (score 4):

For looping over multiple items, use [refs inside v-for](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for).

For joining multiple separate `refs`, use [reactive()](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive):

- **in `<script>`**

```html
<script>
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      el1: null,
      el2: null,
      el3: null
    })
    return toRefs(state)
    // or return { ...toRefs(state), /* moreStuff */ }

  }
})
</script>
```

- **in `<script setup>`**

You have 2 options:

1. do not extract (use them as `state.el1`, `state.el2` in `<template />`)

```html
<script setup>
const state = reactive({
  el1: null,
  el2: null,
  el3: null
})
onMounted(() => {
  console.log(state.el1)
})
</script>
<template>
  <h1 ref="state.el1"></h1>
  <h1 ref="state.el2"></h1>
  <h1 ref="state.el3"></h1>
</template>
```

2. extract them (using `toRefs`) - Con: you have to specify each ref when extracting:

```html
<script setup>
import { reactive, toRefs, onMounted } from 'vue'
const state = reactive({
  el1: null,
  el2: null,
  el3: null
})
const { el1, el2, el3 } = toRefs(state)
onMounted(() => {
  console.log(el1.value)
  console.log(state.el2)
})
</script>
```

The bigger advantage of using `reactive` is that you no longer need to use `.value` inside the `script` (Use `state.el1` in both `<script>` and `<template>`.

Comment: How can loop over these repetive elements if i want use your answer? Is it possible to define a dynamic :ref='item" over the h1 element?

Comment: [Yep](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for). You might want to take your time with Vue documentation. It's really well made and has great examples.

Comment: how can be used? the initial value of el is defined null and when defining a dynamic value, the typescript error appears!.

Comment: This is the third question you ask. You are supposed to ask each question separately, so that by answering I help everyone looking for that answer. By answering here nobody else will benefit from it. Here's [how](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-reactive). Please read [ask].

Comment: Here's [an example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpdj0FqwzAQRa/y0SYOpBFZdGNkQw/QTbdVF8GRG1F7JGTZUITu3rHcupCdZub9N5okXrw/L7MRtVBTF6yPmEycfavJjt6FiIRgrl20iznB0aubKZrbCdG9mR4ZfXAjDmw4aNLUOZrYEK/RoNmDVdIE2GjGqcb7h6Z8/IdLm+EirEr0XHrMSAkXsHHpl8x/7LTBRbV/rKqOaFqUhWvODeY8uM8H77pfye1evpQLHviBEa4AdbNLeeio7hcsT70LjRYES3jWgu/quSwyruov871OtWhTopyVvF9azq4iuZmU3P0i/wDFCoC3) of using with `v-for`. When dealing with arrays, you should still use a single `ref` (with array). Use `reactive` to handle multiple separate refs.

Comment: very appreciated to help to contribute knowledge in the Vue ecosystem. you are right and I try to improve and follow your guide.

Comment: I didn't know we could name `ref` element in a nested object ^^

Comment: @Duannx. Technically, we can't. That's why we need `toRefs`. It takes a reactive object and creates an object with the same keys but each value is a `ref()`. That's what we're passing to `<template>`, by returning `{ ...toRefs(state) }` from normal `<script>` or by deconstructing `const { ... } = toRefs(state)` in `<script setup>`. All those `const`s are individual refs.

Answer (score 4):

Shown in the example below two cases, in `v-for` and through a function `:ref`(if you need to combine elements without a loop):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqNj7FugzAQhl/l5CUgURCwpYDUB+jSNc4QpUexZGzLNizI795zEiCVOmSxdP7u++9uYR/G5POE7Mgad7XCeHDoJ9NxJUajrYcFLPYZaPWpJ+XxGwL0Vo9wIOvwzhUAV1etnAcp6GnhVGZQZVCfCe7gC3tHkLKS0zkltEIvvET3D94mJkkKbQdLnBUdLTGX+idZY/P5IieM0l++J+8dIY3RTXG/la6kwuNo5MUjVQDNUML81mvbciaIgFC3/TmLy9HnOpWzblng1hJCUwzlQ7dbzPEuoIzbPy1jJjckKFNKKJ/E6hWhIqF6CPUrQk1CTUJTbGey8AsFCahz)

Docs: [`Refs inside v-for`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#refs-inside-v-for) and [`Function Refs`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs).

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
  
const list = [1, 2, 3];
const listRefs = ref([]);

const titlesRefs = ref([]);

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(listRefs.value);
  console.log(titlesRefs.value);
})

</script>

<template>
  <h1 v-for="item in list" ref="listRefs">{{ item }}</h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 :ref="el => titlesRefs.push(el)">1</h1>
  <h2 :ref="el => titlesRefs.push(el)">2</h2>
  <h3 :ref="el => titlesRefs.push(el)">3</h3>
</template>
```

Comment: This is really cool `:ref="el => `. Didn't know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following and let me know if that's what you were trying to achieve :)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 ref="el1">Element 1</h1>
    <h1 ref="el2">Element 2</h1>
    <h1 ref="el3">Element 3</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, toRefs, ref } from 'vue';

const state = reactive({
  el1: ref(),
  el2: ref(),
  el3: ref(),
});

const { el1, el2, el3 } = toRefs(state);

console.log(el1, el2, el3);
// ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy(Object), _key: 'el1', _defaultValue: undefined, __v_isRef: true}
// ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy(Object), _key: 'el2', _defaultValue: undefined, __v_isRef: true}
// ObjectRefImpl {_object: Proxy(Object), _key: 'el3', _defaultValue: undefined, __v_isRef: true}
</script>
```

**edit: if you want to loop dynamically, try the following**

```
<template>
  <h1 v-for="el in refsArr" ref="el">{{ el._key }}</h1>
</template>

<script setup>
import { reactive, toRefs, ref } from 'vue';

const state = reactive({
  el1: ref(),
  el2: ref(),
  el3: ref(),
});

const refsObj = toRefs(state);

const refsArr = []
for (const key in refsObj) {
  refsArr.push(refsObj[key]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: i want also, define loop over the h1 elements, how can is it possible to define a dynamic ref atttribute which initial value is null?